# POST request from Ruby to PHP. Unable to fetch data from the PHP page

Tags: php, ruby, http, post

I am working on this Ruby console application which should send a POST request to a PHP file and then print out the outcome in the console. The issue is that the outcome from the PHP file is not getting printed out in the Ruby console app.

This is my Ruby code:

```
require 'net/http'

data = {'command' => 'Test'}
postData = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://localhost/mysite/bin/app/handler.php'), data)
puts postData.body
```

And this is my PHP file:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['command'] . ' test';
?>
```

But this returns nothing. What am I not seeing and what is wrong with this code? I tried pointing to a bad URI and it returned me a `404` HTML page right in the console, but with my correct URI it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Something is wrong with your PHP server.  Perhaps it is not running on port 80 (the HTTP port)? Your code works great when ran using PHP's built-in web server. I.e.,  assuming the PHP script is server.php and the following ruby code is placed in client.rb (note the :8000 part in the URI):

```
# client.rb
require 'net/http'
data = {'command' => 'Test'}
postData = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://localhost:8000/server.php'), data)
puts postData.body
```

Running PHP built-in server on port 8000:

```
cd ~/test
php -S localhost:8000
```

and running the ruby client from the command line:

```
ruby client.rb
```

Produces the expected "Test test" result.